# Jsonata v2.0.0 unexpected output

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, jsonata

Latest JSONata 2.0.0 version gives [Object Promise] as output when run even on the browser without any async functions. Following is the example from the JSONata website.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>JSONata test</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jsonata/jsonata.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      function greeting() {
        var json = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('json').value);
        var result = jsonata('"Hello, " & name').evaluate(json);
        document.getElementById('greeting').innerHTML = result;
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <textarea id="json">{ "name": "Wilbur" }</textarea>
    <button onclick="greeting()">Click me</button>
    <p id="greeting"></p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Why does this happen? I'm currently using v1.8.0 as it doesn't have this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The JSONata team [switched the JSONata evaluator to async functions rather than generators](https://github.com/jsonata-js/jsonata/pull/603).  **This `2.0.0` release introduced a breaking change to the Javascript API, *but no breaking changes to the JSONata language*.** ([release notes](https://github.com/jsonata-js/jsonata/releases/tag/v2.0.0))

From the description on the [Github pull request](https://github.com/jsonata-js/jsonata/pull/583) that necessitated the bump to `2` of the [major version](https://semver.org/#summary) (incompatible version):

> Apart from allowing non-blocking/asynchronous functions - `fetch()`,
> `fs.readFile` etc. to run in parallel, there
> are additional benefits of switching to `async`/`await` - ***performance
> benefits.***

### Per the [documentation](https://docs.jsonata.org/using-browser), the JSONata `v2.0.0` API is now:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>JSONata test</title>
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jsonata/jsonata.min.js"></script>
    <script>
      // `async`
      async function greeting() {
        var json = JSON.parse(document.getElementById('json').value);
        // `await`
        var result = await jsonata('"Hello, " & name').evaluate(json);
        document.getElementById('greeting').innerHTML = result;
      }
    </script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <textarea id="json">{ "name": "Wilbur" }</textarea>
    <button onclick="greeting()">Click me</button>
    <p id="greeting"></p>
  </body>
</html>
```